# what do you think design an on-line newspaper?

Tags: website-design, navigation

I got a practice project to design a online version for a printed newspaper.
The basically thing is to reorganize the information, and the navigation would deal with this. What others do you think is important too.

Welcome to any advice and ideas.

Comment: It sounds like you're practically asking for someone to do your homework.  I suggest that you come up with some designs and then submit another question to get feedback on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few pointers, as your question is terribly broad. Your design has to consider the following questions:

- How does an online newspaper differ from a printed one?

  - What do users expect from an online newspaper?
  - What does the publisher expect?
- How will employees manage and update the site? How does that integrate with the current publishing process?

Answer (score 1):

Watch this [inspiring TED talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/jacek_utko_asks_can_design_save_the_newspaper.html) by Jacek Utko about newspaper design.

Your approach should be led by the **culture of the newspaper**. Look at what you can add.

- If it is a hi-brow, information rich
  paper, then look at what you can do
  for the graphs and charts to add value in
  the transition to web.
- If it is a
  more pop-culture paper, then
  look at what you can do for the pop-up
  boxes on triva about celebs, how you
  can make the horoscope more dynamic.

Do some research on **what parts of a paper are read most**.  It might surprise you.  Focus your energies on those parts.  Check your site is fully **usable on mobile devices** with small screens.